# IOS Phonegap hybrid testing automation

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, accessibility

I'm using calabash-cucumber for testing automation. It's working for IOS native pages.

I was able to set accessibility label for native elements. eg: `button.accessibilitylabel=@"Button"`.

Can anyone tell me how to set accessibility labels for IOS Phonegap hybrid pages. either in html or javascript. eg: for `<p>` tags